# javascript promise handling, fail to handle error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, promise

I'm having some trouble understanding what I'm doing wrong. I have a function that receives a url to which should make a GET request, in case of success should fill a combo with the received data (this depends which function calls it), in case of fail it should execute some common code.

```
    getFirstCombo = () => {
        this.getFromApi('/First/GetAll')
            .then(data => this.setState({firstComboOptions: this.parseCombo(data)}))
            .catch(error => console.log('ERROR2: ', error));
    }

    getSecondCombo = () => {
        this.getFromApi('/Second/GetAll')
            .then(data => this.setState({secondComboOptions: this.parseCombo(data)}))
            .catch(error => console.log('ERROR2: ', error));
    }

    parseCombo = (data: any) => {
        const combo = data.map(item => (
            { label: item.description, value: item.id }
        ));
        return combo;
    }

    getFromApi = (url: string) : Promise<any> => {
        return restApiAxios.get(url)
        .then(response => {
            return response.data;
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log('ERROR: ', error);
        });
    }
```

this code is executed on the componentDidMount of the react component, but when it fails, it first prints :

```
ERROR:  Error: Network Error
    at createError (createError.js:16)
    at XMLHttpRequest.handleError (xhr.js:83)
```

and immediately after:

```
PanelDatos.tsx:50 ERROR2:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
    at PanelDatos.parseCombo (PanelDatos.tsx:55)
    at PanelDatos.tsx:50
```

so, when failing executes the *catch* block from *getFromApi* and then it tries to execute the *then* block in *getFirstCombo*, which triggers the *catch* block from the same function cause data does not exist, why is that? shouldnt it just execute the first *catch*?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

`.catch` returns a promise much like `.then`, allowing you to return a custom value and handle it that way.

Try doing the following to observe the effect:

```js
Promise
  .reject(1)
  .catch(e => e) // Catch the error and return it
  .then(console.log) // will log 1 to the console
```

This means you'll need to add some checks if you want to continue to use promises like this:

```js
Promise
  .reject(new Error('haha'))
  .catch(err => ({err}))
  .then(({err, data}) => {
    if(err) return // Do nothing
    // enter code here
  })
```

However, using `async / await` will improve readability even more:

```js
getFirstCombo = async () => {
  let response
  try {
    response = await this.getFromApi('/First/GetAll')
  } catch (e) {
    return // Exit early
  }
  let parsed
  try {
    parsed = this.parseCombo(data)
  } catch (e) {
    console.log(e)
    return // Exit early
  }
  return this.setState({firstComboOptions: parsed})
}
```

And, of course, throw the error again in your catch block in your api to allow it to handle api calls.

Comment: ok so if I want to handle the errors in one place I should put the code inside the getFromApi catch block and the return a Promis.reject(), and in the getFirstCombo only do the then with no catch, right?

Answer (score 1):

This is happening since inside `getFromApi` catch method on the error you are not returning anything, so by default, it is returning a resolved promise with `null` response and the execution goes inside `getFirstCombo` then method, causing another error. You can update your code to resolve this like:

```
getFromApi = (url: string): Promise<any> => {
   return restApiAxios.get(url)
      .then(response => response.data)
      .catch(error => Promise.reject(error));
}
```

The static [`Promise.reject`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/reject) function returns a `Promise` that is rejected. So, it will go directly into `catch` of wherever `getFromApi` is called.

DEMO:

```js
async function getFromApi(url) {
   return fetch(url) // rejects
      .then(response => response.json())
      .catch(err => Promise.reject(err))
}
async function getFirstCombo() {
   getFromApi('https://no-such-server.abcd')
      .then(data => console.log('data: ', data))
      .catch(error => console.log('ERROR2: ', error));
}
getFirstCombo()
```

DEMO #2  <sub>(With `getFirstCombo` function not having any catch block)</sub> :

```js
async function getFromApi(url) {
  return fetch(url) // rejects
    .then(response => response.json())
    .catch(err => {
      console.log('ERROR in getFromApi(): ', err);
      return null;  // return null, empty array, 0 or false... as per your requirement
    })
}
async function getFirstCombo() {
  getFromApi('https://no-such-server.abcd')
    .then(data => console.log('data: ', data))
    // Same value set in catch block of getFromApi will return in this then() block
    // Validate this `data` variable before processing it further like:
    // if(data === null) this means an error had occurred
    // else continue with your logic
}
getFirstCombo()
```

Comment: awesome, so if I want to handle the errors in one place I should put the code inside the getFromApi catch block and the return a Promis.reject(), and in the getFirstCombo only do the then with no catch, right?

Comment: If you want that behaviour then you can modify the code inside the `getFromApi` catch block as I have done in the new posted demo, then you will not need any catch inside the `getFirstCombo`